# Copying Folder containing few other folders to a specific directory

Tags: python, wxpython

I would really love to know on how to copy a folder containing some other folder to a specific directory.

I've created a `wx.FileDialog` to find locate the origin folder(path_origin) and to specify the `new_directory`( directory in which the origin file will be copied to)

Below is my code

```
import os
import wx
import shutil


def transfer_folder():

app = wx.PySimpleApp()


    dialog1 = wx.FileDialog(None, 'Select file:','','')
    if dialog1.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        path_origin=dialog1.GetCurrentlySelectedFilename()

wildcard = "Nastran Input (*.bdf; *.dat; *.nas)|*.bdf;*.dat;*.nas|" \
    "All files (*.*)|*.*"
    dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, 'Select file:','','',wildcard)
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        new_directory=dialog.GetPath()

shutil.copy2(str(path_origin), str(new_directory))
```

Another problem is that, I can't select the folder to be copied since it has a other folders inside it.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try using copytree?

```
shutil.copytree(str(path_origin), str(new_directory))
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html supports copytree

**shutil.copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None)**

*Recursively copy an entire directory tree rooted at src. The destination directory, named by dst, must not already exist; it will be created as well as missing parent directories. Permissions and times of directories are copied with copystat(), individual files are copied using shutil.copy2().*

Comment: I have a problem in which I cant select the folder i wanted to copy. When i selected the folder and i click ok on the filedialog, it enters into the folder, thus i cant really copy the folder. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I'm not expert in wxpython - but can you try using "wx.DirDialog" instead of "wx.FileDialog"?  see https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/751284-wxpython-filedialog-select-folder

Comment: see also: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0380__wxPython/ChooseadirectoryfromDirDialog.htm